# Why does tcsh consistently have multiple fd's pointing to /dev/tty

Tags: tcsh, file-descriptors

This is on Ubuntu 16.04, with bash 4.3.42 and tcsh 6.19

If a open a virtual console not being used by X and run bash, I see stdin, stdout, stderr and a dedicated file descriptor for the tty (apparently).

```
$ cd /dev/fd
$ ls
0 1 2 255
$ ls -al .
... .
... ..
... 0 -> /dev/tty3
... 1 -> /dev/tty3
... 2 -> /dev/tty3
... 255 -> /dev/tty3
```

If I'm using tcsh, I see five non-std{in, out, err} file descriptors pointing to the tty and std{in, out, err} are all mapped to `/dev/null`.

```
% cd /dev/fd
% ls -al
... .
... ..
... 0 -> /dev/null
... 1 -> /dev/null
... 15 -> /dev/tty3
... 16 -> /dev/tty3
... 17 -> /dev/tty3
... 18 -> /dev/tty3
... 19 -> /dev/tty3
... 2 -> /dev/null
```

Why would `tcsh` need so many file descriptors all pointing to the tty and what is the benefit of mapping 0,1, and 2 to `/dev/null`? Wouldn't that just mean that slightly more bookkeeping is needed when `tcsh` forks processes so they write to / read from the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tcsh` is organized differently from `bash` (no surprise).  Both are old, and full of interesting quirks for the careful reader.

This difference is due to the way `tcsh` manages file descriptors.  Unlike `bash`, it does not provide the script writer with a way to manipulate numbered file descriptors.  The developers found it convenient to organize its file descriptors by [moving](https://github.com/tcsh-org/tcsh/blob/master/sh.misc.c#L338) the standard streams into a "saved" area (unused by real scripts), and when running commands, it [duplicates](https://github.com/tcsh-org/tcsh/blob/master/sh.misc.c#L363) those to commands (i.e., a subprocess), and [closes](https://github.com/tcsh-org/tcsh/blob/master/sh.misc.c#L320) them when the commands complete.

In the source code, [`sh.h` has this chunk](https://github.com/tcsh-org/tcsh/blob/master/sh.h#L201) which explains the use of those file descriptors:

```
/*
 * The shell moves std in/out/diag and the old std input away from units
 * 0, 1, and 2 so that it is easy to set up these standards for invoked
 * commands.
 */
#define FSAFE   5               /* We keep the first 5 descriptors untouched */
#define FSHTTY  15              /* /dev/tty when manip pgrps */
#define FSHIN   16              /* Preferred desc for shell input */
#define FSHOUT  17              /* ... shell output */
#define FSHDIAG 18              /* ... shell diagnostics */
#define FOLDSTD 19              /* ... old std input */
```

For both shells, there are multiple links to the same "real" device in `/dev/fd` (for Linux, at least), because that is the way the pseudo-terminal driver is organized.

You will, by the way, get a different result if you run `tcsh` from another shell.  But if your default shell is `tcsh`, likely you will see those file descriptors as described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly something in your `tcsh` configuration (e.g. `~/.login`, `~/.cshrc` `/etc/csh.*`) - look for anything that redirects stdin, stdout, stderr.

When I run `tcsh` on my system, I get:

```
$ tcsh
> ls -lF /dev/fd/
total 0
lrwx------ 1 cas cas 64 Jun 26 13:28 0 -> /dev/pts/29
lrwx------ 1 cas cas 64 Jun 26 13:28 1 -> /dev/pts/29
lrwx------ 1 cas cas 64 Jun 26 13:28 2 -> /dev/pts/29
lr-x------ 1 cas cas 64 Jun 26 13:28 3 -> /proc/16570/fd/
```

Comment: obligatory ps: csh and tcsh are evil....put on this earth to tempt people into bad scripting.

Comment: According to Stephen Bourne, `csh` came about because Bill Joy asked him to add  - I think - command history and job control to the original borne shell, Bourne told him he was too busy, so then Bill Joy created csh.

Comment: yes, well, the demonic forces behind csh **would** say that, wouldn't they?

Comment: Yep. that's definitely right. If I do an `exec tcsh -f` then stdin and stdout and not redirected and I don't have any unnecessary open descriptors. I made the mistake of attempting to use `tcsh` a few months ago and now I can't get it out of my muscle memory :/