# Invisible prompt after global redirection of stderr to /dev/null

Tags: bash, debian, io-redirection

Studying [TLDP's Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ioredirintro.html) I am unable to reconstruct the following shell output in bash 4.4.12 in debian 9, both from tty and pts:

```
bash$ lsof -a -p $$ -d0,1,2
COMMAND PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME
 bash    363 bozo        0u   CHR  136,1         3 /dev/pts/1
 bash    363 bozo        1u   CHR  136,1         3 /dev/pts/1
 bash    363 bozo        2u   CHR  136,1         3 /dev/pts/1


bash$ exec 2> /dev/null
bash$ lsof -a -p $$ -d0,1,2
COMMAND PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME
 bash    371 bozo        0u   CHR  136,1         3 /dev/pts/1
 bash    371 bozo        1u   CHR  136,1         3 /dev/pts/1
 bash    371 bozo        2w   CHR    1,3       120 /dev/null
```

Whenever I run the second command the shell prompt disappears and all keyboard input stops being displayed, though I can still run commands and see their output. Why is that?

Comment: Because bash prints your prompt on stderr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which stream does Bash write its prompt to?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20826/which-stream-does-bash-write-its-prompt-to)

Comment: This question asks about keyboard input, which that one does not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because you have redirected the shell's standard error.

That's where a POSIX-conformant shell is supposed to write its interactive prompts, according to the standard.

- The [Bourne Again](https://gnu.org/software/bash/), [Heirloom Bourne](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html), ([Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/ksh) and [FreeBSD](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/shells/ksh93/pkg-descr?view=markup)) [93 Korn](http://kornshell.com/), [MirBSD Korn](https://mirbsd.org/mksh.htm), ([FreeBSD](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/shells/pdksh/pkg-descr?view=markup), OpenBSD, and [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/posh)) PD Korn, ([FreeBSD](https://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh) and [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/dash)) Almquist, and [Watanabe](http://yash.osdn.jp/) shells all conform in this regard and write their interactive prompts to standard error.  You will see the lack of prompt behaviour with all of them.

  The not echoing input behaviour is however a lot more complex:

  - The Debian PD Korn, Debian Almquist, and Heirloom Bourne shells do not implement their own line editors, but rely upon the one provided by the terminal line discipline in the kernel.  You will still see echoed what you type as their standard input.
  - The Watanabe, (FreeBSD 93) Korn, and (Debian 93) Korn shells implement their own line editors which *also* write to standard error when they (re-)display the input lines as they are being edited.  However, they turn terminal echo *on* before executing the `exec` command, and (because standard error is no longer a terminal device) *fail to turn it off again* when invoking the line editor for their next input.  Thus you will see further input that you type echoed by the terminal line discipline, even though the input echo from the shell's line editor is going to the now redirected standard error.  Their line editors also go wrong in subtle ways, such as not recognizing any further terminal size changes.
  - The MirBSD Korn, (FreeBSD PD) Korn, and (OpenBSD PD) Korn shells implement their own line editors that (re-)display the edited line to standard error, but open another file descriptor to `/dev/tty` directly in order to control things like terminal echo.  They *succeed* in turning echo off again when invoking the line editor for its next input.  Thus you will *not* see further input that you type echoed by their line editors *or* the terminal line discipline.
  - The Bourne Again and FreeBSD Almquist shells implement their own line editors that (re-)display the edited line to standard error, but use standard *input* to control things like terminal echo.  They *succeed* in turning echo off again when invoking the line editor for its next input.  Thus you will *not* see further input that you type echoed by their line editors *or* the terminal line discipline.
- The [BusyBox Almquist](https://busybox.net/) and [Z](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/) shells do not conform to POSIX in this regard.  They both implement their own line editors.  With both, you will see the behaviour that that appendix leads you to believe will occur.

  - The BusyBox Almquist shell's line editor uses standard output for input echo, and that is *also* where it writes its prompts.  It is simply unaffected by redirection of standard error.  But you can get the effect by redirecting standard output instead.  It uses standard input for recognizing terminal size changes.
  - The Z shell goes to some effort to try to find a terminal device to run ZLE against, up to and including explicitly opening `/dev/tty`.  It duplicates a file descriptor to the terminal device at startup and ZLE then uses that for *everything*; for echoing typed input, for *reading* typed input, for writing interactive prompts to, and for turning terminal echo on and off.  So ZLE is unaffected by subsequent redirection of standard error, output, or indeed even input.  You can have all three redirected to `/dev/null` by `exec` if you like, and the Z shell will still interactively prompt you for and receive input.

(The [Thompson](https://etsh.io/) shell does not support the shell `exec` command mechanism in the first place, because it pre-dates its invention.)

You should complain to author Stéphane Chazelas that that appendix is wrong, so that it might get fixed.

## Further reading

- "[Shell variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03)".  *Shell and Utilities*.  Base Specifications. IEEE 1003.1:2017.  The Open Group.  2017.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299440/5132

Comment: No.  [Debian PD Korn](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/posh).  [Debian 93 Korn](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/ksh).  [FreeBSD PD Korn](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/shells/pdksh/pkg-descr?view=markup).  [FreeBSD 93 Korn](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/shells/ksh93/pkg-descr?view=markup).

Comment: A note: debian "posh" only runs on Linux since it requires glibc-specific bugs to be present in libc. A funny fact, affected source parts: all files with GPL header. BTW: I am the author of the first history line editor that was integrated into a shell. The related shell, called `bsh` is from 1984 `ksh` added a line editor in 1986, Since 2006, this editor is also integrated into the maintained Bourne Shell. It writes the prompt to stderr, reads input from stdin, controls the termial via stdin and writes echos to stdout. If you type `^R` to redisplay, prompt goes to stderr, the rest to stdout.