# What does zsh's -i option actually do?

Tags: shell, zsh

From the `zsh` man page:

```
   -c     Take the first argument as a command to execute, rather than reading commands  from  a  script  or  standard
          input.   If  any  further  arguments are given, the first one is assigned to $0, rather than being used as a
          positional parameter.

   -i     Force shell to be interactive.  It is still possible to specify a script to execute.

   -s     Force shell to read commands from the standard input.  If the -s flag is not  present  and  an  argument  is
          given, the first argument is taken to be the pathname of a script to execute.
```

As far as I can tell, `-i` has no effect except when used with `-c`, to force `zsh` to source `~/.zshrc`. Without `-c`, `zsh` appears to be interactive be default.

So:

- Is there any difference between `zsh` and `zsh -i`?
- Is there any difference between `zsh -s` and `zsh -s -i`?
- Does `-i` do anything if `-c` is not present?

Comment: "It is still possible to specify a script to execute."

Comment: `zsh` is only "interactive by default" if its stdin is a tty. You may want to run an interactive zsh when that is not the case. Just try `echo val | zsh -i`, then at the prompt enter `read key; echo $key`. Got it?

Comment: @mosvy Your example causes all known shells to print the warning: missing file argument.

Comment: @schily which example?

Comment: Your example `echo val | zsh -i`

Comment: @mosvy Thanks, that was a good example.

Comment: @schily I got no such warning.

Comment: @jth This is another reason why you cannot count `zsh` as a compliant shell. It is just too different from a real shell  :-(

Comment: When "all known shells" does not encompass the PD Korn, Debian Almquist, FreeBSD Almquist, '93 Korn, Heirloom Bourne, and Z shells, as is the case here (no such warning being emitted by any of them), then exactly how many shells one knows needs to be reëvaluated.

Answer (score 4):

The confusion here stems from a misunderstanding of what it means to be an *interactive* shell.

A Z shell is not interactive just because it happens to be running a prompt-read-execute loop.  One can have a shell that is *not* interactive running a prompt-read-execute loop, reading its commands from a file or from a pipe.  `cat | zsh` yields exactly that.

A Z shell is interactive if it has no command or script to run (i.e. it drops into that prompt-read-execute loop) *and* its standard input is a terminal.  This is a decision made by the shell program at startup.  Lots of things are *affected by* the decision and are *consequences of* it, such as what startup files to process and the *initial* values of the `$-` shell variable and `interactive` shell option.  See the manual for all of the various things that occur "in an interactive shell".

There are some very slight variations among shells on the exact rule used.  Some (such as the Z shell here) only test standard input to see whether it is a terminal.  The Single UNIX Specification says that both standard input and standard error should be checked.  `zsh 2>&1 | cat` yields an interactive Z shell, but `ksh 2>&1 | cat` will yield a non-interactive Korn shell.

The Z shell *also* decides whether it goes into a prompt-read-execute loop, runs a command, or executes a script.  That is a *separate* decision, whose result feeds into the am-I-interactive decision.  *All three choices* can be either interactive or non-interactive, with use of the `-i` option.

The `-i` option is simply a way of forcing a shell to think that it is interactive, *even if* its standard input is not a terminal, or it is given a command or a script to run.  It is a bit tricky to demonstrate that with a pipeline such as `cat | zsh -i` because ZLE causes some odd behaviour (more on which at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434839/5132) that muddies the water a bit.  But you can see it with `ksh -i 2>&1 | cat` which yields an interactive Korn shell.

The `-s` option is similarly present to override the *other* (what-to-do) decision, based when not overridden upon the presence of a first argument, to execute a script rather than run a prompt-read-execute loop.  The `-c` option affects that other decision, too.

- `zsh wibble` tries to execute a script, and is non-interactive because of that.
- `zsh -s wibble` does not try to execute a script but forces the what-to-do decision to choose to enter a prompt-read-execute loop, and (when standard input is a terminal) is interactive.
- `zsh -c wibble` is non-interactive, because it is running a command.

The combinations fall out logically from here.

- `zsh -si wibble` is still (likewise) interactive, the override forcing the am-I-interactive decision the same way that it is being made anyway (because `-s` is forcing the choice of going into the prompt-read-execute loop).
- `zsh -i wibble` tries to execute a script, but the script (if it looks) will think that it is an interactive shell and the interactive EOF behaviour will occur when the Z shell reaches the end of the script.
- `zsh -ci wibble` still runs a command, but if that command looks (if it is a builtin or a shell function) it will think that it is an interactive shell.

… with two exceptions:

- `zsh -cs wibble` runs a command, in a shell that thinks that it is non-interactive.
- `zsh -csi wibble` likewise runs a command, in a shell that thinks that it is interactive.

`-c` effectively overrides `-s`.  (Microsoft/IBM/JPSoftware command interpreters have a `/K` option that runs a command *then* drops into the prompt-read-execute loop.  This would be the logical combination of `-c` and `-s`, but that was never done in the world of Unix shells.)

Comment: "A Z shell is interactive if it has no command or script to run [...] and its standard input is a terminal" This seems incorrect. You can still specify a command or script to run with the `-i` option.

Comment: It only seems incorrect on that ground, to someone who has not read beyond that sentence to the rest of the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. It seems to be an incorrect statement that does not add anything to the rest of the answer.

Comment: Overall, I appreciate the detailed response. Unfortunately I do not have the time to verify all of the information in the answer, so I don't feel I can accept the answer as correct; but I will upvote it because it seems useful.