# tab completion of /proc/self/fd/ shows different completions compared with listed contents

Tags: linux, zsh, proc

Using zsh, if I try tab completion of the following command `ls /proc/self/fd/` then I see the following:

```
files
0@   1@   10@  11@  12@  13   2@   3
```

However, when I press enter (without completing) I see:

```
> ls /proc/self/fd/
0  1  2  3
```

If I list the file descriptors for the current shell I get something different:

```
> ls /proc/$$/fd/
0  1  10  2
```

Why are these three results different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s start with `ls /proc/self/fd`: that shows the file descriptors open for the `ls` process. These are the three standard input, output and error descriptors, and the descriptor for the directory `ls` is reading.

`ls /proc/$$/fd` shows the file descriptors which are still open in the shell while `ls` is running: the three standard descriptors, and `zsh`’s copy of the terminal file descriptor (10).

Tab-completing `ls /proc/self/fd/` shows the file descriptors open *at that moment* for the shell. In addition to those shown by `ls /proc/$$/fd`, this includes file descriptors open for the completion itself (to files in `/usr/share/zsh/.../functions` implementing the completion).

Comment: That's cleared things up a lot, thankyou! I have another question though; why does zsh need another file descriptor for the terminal? the 3 standard descriptors already point to the terminal.

Comment: Answer comments are not for follow-on questions, and we do in fact already have the answer to that in an answer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/434812/5132 . (-:

Comment: OK, but for anyone reading this and wondering the same thing; apparently zsh uses its own file descriptor for printing the prompt & command line, unlike bash which uses stderr for this.